# Mi aplicación se cierra en KK pero funciona en Lollipop o superior

Tags: java, android

Mi aplicación no funciona en KK, se detiene cuando la abro, dejo aquí el logcat:

```
01-30 16:38:36.122 13983-13983/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-30 16:38:36.296 13983-13983/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-30 16:38:36.296 13983-13983/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-30 16:38:37.158 13996-13996/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-30 16:38:37.330 13996-13996/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-30 16:38:37.330 13996-13996/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-30 16:38:45.187 14007-14007/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-30 16:38:45.356 14007-14007/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-30 16:38:45.356 14007-14007/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-30 16:38:46.239 14025-14025/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-30 16:38:46.407 14025-14025/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-30 16:38:46.407 14025-14025/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-30 16:38:46.509 14025-14031/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
01-30 16:38:46.509 14025-14031/? E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
01-30 16:38:46.606 14035-14035/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
01-30 16:38:47.985 14035-14035/vrteam.technophonecs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: otrointento.dos, PID: 14035
                                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Window.setNavigationBarColor
                                                                          at otrointento.dos.descubre_Activity.onCreate(descubre_Activity.java:57)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Por lo que puedo entender el error está en la clase ***descubre_activity*** pero no sé como solucionarlo, por que no sé el error real, dejo la clase aquí por si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias

**descubre_activity:**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class descubre_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;
    ImageButton btn3;
    ImageButton btn4;
    ImageButton btn5;
    ImageButton icon_des1;
    ImageButton icon_des2;
    ImageButton icon_des3;
    ImageButton icon_des4;
    ImageButton icon_des5;
    ImageButton icon_des6;
    ImageButton icon_work1;
    ImageButton icon_work2;
    ImageButton icon_work3;
    ImageButton icon_work4;
    ImageButton icon_work5;

    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 10;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // PERMISO CONCEDIDO, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:00000000"));
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    // PERMISO DENEGADO
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.descubre_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.text_des);
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        icon_des1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des1);
        icon_des2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des2);
        icon_des3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des3);
        icon_des4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des4);
        icon_des5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des5);
        icon_des6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des6);
        icon_work1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_work1);
        icon_work2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_work2);
        icon_work3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_work3);
        icon_work4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_work4);
        icon_work5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_work5);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, descubre_Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton2 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, reparar_Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton3 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, smartphones_Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton4 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, iphone_Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton5 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, diseno_Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton5);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent icon_des4 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, gmail_Activity.class);
                startActivity(icon_des4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(descubre_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Aquí ya está concedido, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:00000000"));
                    startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    // Aquí lanzamos un dialog para que el usuario confirme si permite o no el realizar llamadas
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(descubre_Activity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                }
            }
        });

        icon_des6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_work1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent work1 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, work1Activity.class);
                startActivity(work1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_work2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent work2 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, work2Activity.class);
                startActivity(work2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_work3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent work3 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, work3Activity.class);
                startActivity(work3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_work4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent work4 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, work4Activity.class);
                startActivity(work4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_work5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent work5 = new Intent(descubre_Activity.this, work5Activity.class);
                startActivity(work5);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Android K.K esta entre tu API mínima ?

Comment: Sí, es la minima 4.4 @FelixBeeb

Comment: @FelixBeeb parece ser por esta linea, no es compatible con KK?   getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));

Comment: Si y aparte no puede leer los ficheros - E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El método setNavigationBarColor(int) se introdujo en el API 21, lollipop, entiendo que para versiones anteriores tendrás que modificar el código para que funcione.

Para evitar el error en KitKat:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));
}
```

Por supuesto, con esta solución no se cambiaría el color de la NavigationBar en KitKat.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, eso he comentado arriba, cómo podría usar ese código (o uno similiar) para que funcione tanto en KK como superiores? @pablo

Comment: @UserNameYo intenta con ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name) si deseas el color

Comment: @UserNameYo Si eso se implementó en la API 21, es imposible poder utilizar algo similar en API's anteriores.

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado @pablo

Answer (score 0):

Verifica cual es la versión mínima del SDK de tu app:

Click derecho al directiorio de tu app

Selecciona la opcion Open Module Settings

Te mostrara el siguiente cuadro y dale click a la pestaña Flavors:

y revisa Min SDK Version

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]